# Symfony2 setSelected value of Entity Type

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

This might wound like a silly question, but I'm stuck. I've the following field in a form of my Symfony2 application:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('match_team1','entity', array(
            'class'     => 'MyAppBundle:Team',
            'expanded'  => false,
            'multiple'  => false,
            'label'     => 'Team 1',
            'mapped'    => true,
            'property'  => 'name'

        ));
}
```

Match Class

```
class Match
{


/**
 * @var integer
 */
private $id;


/**
 * @var integer
 */
private $match_number;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $match_type;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 */
private $match_date;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $match_status;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $match_team1;

 /**
 * Set matchTeam1
 *
 * @param string $matchTeam1
 *
 * @return Match
 */
public function setMatchTeam1($matchTeam1)
{
    $this->match_team1 = $matchTeam1;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get matchTeam1
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getMatchTeam1()
{
    return $this->match_team1;
}
```

Edit function:

```
private function createEditForm(Match $entity)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new MatchType(), $entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('match_update', array('id' =>     $entity->getId())),
        'method' => 'PUT',
    ));


    $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Update'));

    return $form;
}
```

But when I update the form the selected value from the drop down does not stay. In the database I can see the entry but in the form it's not being displayed. Can anyone help me to set the selected value?

Comment: you need t show us your entity (the use used as data for that form)

Comment: you mean Team Entity? I am using this form in Match Entity. In match Entity Im adding the Team entity with property name

Comment: Show us how look $match_team1 doctrine config in your Match entity.

Comment: I have added the Match Entity

Comment: "In the database I can see the entry" - Does that mean that match_team1_id is being set in the database table?  Or is it null?

Comment: In database the name saves not the id like 'Netherlands', yes it saves not null. The problem is  when i click eidt the form all time the first values are showing  not the one i saved or is in db

Comment: also added the controller action

Comment: I'm pretty sure need to add a Datatransformer because in option value I see id and in db it saves string name that's why its not working